# Java convert String to date and then Comparison

Tags: java, date, datetime, comparison

I have a 2D String array

```
static String[][] TaskStorage = {
{"Task 1","02/07/13"},  
{"Task 2","02/08/13"},  
{"Task 3","02/09/13"},  
{"Task 4","02/10/13"},  
{"Task 5","02/11/13"},  
{"Task 6","02/03/13"},  
{"Task 7","02/04/13"},  
{"Task 8","02/05/13"},  
{"Task 9","02/06/13"},  
{"Task 10","03/01/13"}, 
{"Task 11","03/02/13"}, 
{"Task 12","03/03/13"}, 
};
```

I would like to print all TaskStorage[0][i] where TaskStorage[i][1] is 02/07 and 02/08. 
Taking into consideration that todayDate is 02/04. Today date can change to 02/28.
todayDate will be based on the execution time of the code.
Basically printing tasks that are two days ahead.

This is what I've tried:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yy");
TaskDate = dateFormat.parse(LinkStorage[i][1]);
if (todayDate.after(TaskDate)) {
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: and what did you try so far?

Comment: Ok, good to know, good luck with coding :)

Comment: @Dan Below is what I have tried.
   SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yy");  
   TaskDate = dateFormat.parse(LinkStorage[i][1]); 
   if (todayDate.after(TaskDate)) 
   {System.out.println("")} 
 
Unfortunately not getting desired output

Comment: @user2041390 If you want a quick answer then it is in your best interest to put that information in the question when you ask it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse the strings to `Date` objects and then do the comparisons through the `Date` API.

**Edit for change to Question:**

> Below is what I have tried.
>
> ```
> SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yy");  
> TaskDate = dateFormat.parse(LinkStorage[i][1]);  
> if (todayDate.after(TaskDate)) {  
>     System.out.println("")  
> }
> ```
>
> Unfortunately not getting desired output

The problem is with your format string, you are asking for **Minutes** and not **Months**. Change `"mm/dd/yy"` to `"MM/dd/yy"` and you should have better luck.