# Rally: Check if Iteration falls in a Release

Tags: rally

I have to check if a given Iteration comes under a given release.For example: Iteration 5.2 falls under Release PSI 5. I guess the only way to do this is to check if: `IterationStartDate >= ReleaseStartDate && IterationEndDate<= ReleaseDate` ( I am using Rally Java toolkit). My question is:

1. How to convert the returned JsonElement (Iteration or Release date) into a date format that can be used to compare the dates? ( is it the SimpleDateFormat class? ).  I have a Iteration and Release class that I am using to contain values.

Later on in the code, I want to do something like:

```
if(iteration.startDate >= release.startDate && iteration.endDate <= release.endDate){
 System.out.println("The Iteration "+iteration.name+" falls under "+release.name);
}
```

I tried it on my own and also looked it up but couldn't find a relevant answer. Thanks.

EDIT:

Is this the right way to compare?

```
DateFormat iterationStartDate = new SimpleDateFormat(iter.StartDate()); //iter.StartDate() is of type String
DateFormat iterationEndDate = new SimpleDateFormat(iter.EndDate());
DateFormat releaseStartDate = new SimpleDateFormat(release.StartDate());
DateFormat releaseEndDate = new SimpleDateFormat(release.EndDate());
//then compare
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of querying iterations by release dates:

```
public class FindIterationsByReleaseDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {


        String host = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
            String username = "user@co.com";
            String password = "secret";
            String projectRef = "/project/1234";
            String applicationName = "RESTExampleFindReleasesByProject";

            RallyRestApi restApi = null;

        try {
                restApi = new RallyRestApi(
                        new URI(host),
                        username,
                        password);
                restApi.setApplicationName(applicationName); 

                System.out.println(restApi.getWsapiVersion()); 

                QueryRequest  releaseRequest = new QueryRequest("Release");
                releaseRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("ReleaseStartDate", "ReleaseDate"));
                releaseRequest.setScopedDown(false);
                releaseRequest.setScopedUp(false);
                releaseRequest.setProject(projectRef);
                releaseRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Name", "=", "r1"));

                QueryResponse releaseQueryResponse = restApi.query(releaseRequest);

                JsonObject releaseJsonObject = releaseQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();

                String rsd = releaseJsonObject.get("ReleaseStartDate").getAsString();
                String rd = releaseJsonObject.get("ReleaseDate").getAsString();

                QueryRequest  iterationRequest = new QueryRequest("Iteration");
                iterationRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Name","StartDate","EndDate"));
                iterationRequest.setScopedDown(false);
                iterationRequest.setScopedUp(false);
                iterationRequest.setProject(projectRef);
                iterationRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("StartDate", ">=", rsd).and(new QueryFilter("EndDate", "<=", rd)));

                QueryResponse iterationQueryResponse = restApi.query(iterationRequest);
                int numberOfIteraitons = iterationQueryResponse.getTotalResultCount();
                System.out.println(numberOfIteraitons);
                if(numberOfIteraitons >0){
                    for (int i=0;i<numberOfIteraitons;i++){
                        JsonObject iterationJsonObject = iterationQueryResponse.getResults().get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                        System.out.println(iterationJsonObject.get("Name"));
                    }
                }       
        }
        finally{
            if (restApi != null) {
                restApi.close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: can this be done without querying Rally? I have a ArrayList of releases and iterations, I only need to check for each release, if any iterations fall in that release based on their start and end date. I don't want to query it in Rally.

Comment: For simplicity, Lets say I have:
1. String startDate = iteration.get("StartDate").getAsString();
2. String endDate = iteration.get("EndDate").getAsString();
How to check if startDate < endDate?

Comment: That's exactly what I did in the code: String rsd = releaseJsonObject.get("ReleaseStartDate").getAsString();
String rd = releaseJsonObject.get("ReleaseDate").getAsString();
iterationRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("StartDate", ">=", rsd).and(new QueryFilter("EndDate", "<=", rd)));

Comment: I don't want to query it in Rally. Can I just convert these date strings into some date class and compare? My only question is if I can convert your String rd and String rsd into some equivalent date class objects and compare them.

Comment: Per API's documentation, QueryFilter takes String values as parameters: QueryFilter(String field, String operator, String value) http://rallytools.github.io/RallyRestToolkitForJava/ I am not sure I understand what you mean by not querying in Rally, but if this is unrelated to Rally and a Java question of converting a String to a date and then comparing dates maybe this post will help: "Java convert String to date and then Comparison"
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697927/java-convert-string-to-date-and-then-comparison

Comment: I think you are right, this should be a Java question. Thanks.